# how to find the self intersection of parametric curve

Tags: calculus

$(\sin 2t,\sin 3t),0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

I've tried almost everything but can't get when the curve crosses itself. Could someone help me? thank you very much.

Comment: Method is to make two versions of the point, one using the original parameter t, and the other using another parameter say s, then trying to solve the system obtained by setting first coordinates equal and setting second coordinates equal. This is because parameter values differ at self crossings.

Comment: [Hint](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/i6jb4tgsdx). Quite obvious where the first $t$ is.

Comment: What does "almost everything" entail?